# .htaccess authentication for only one subdirectory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdirectory

I have a .htaccess file that is requesting login credentials on every page of my website. The .htaccess is located only within my dev folder. However whenever I go to my live website(not dev) Im still asked for login credentials.

**What I would like:** To only have .htaccess request password on my dev subdirectory. So for example when I go to dev.mywebsite.com I will be asked for the login credentials.

- This is my file path for my live website /www/live_website
- This is my file path for my dev website /www/live_website/dev

(The .htaccess file only exists in the /www/live_website/dev)

Here is what my .htaccess looks like:

```
AuthUserFile /www/live_website/dev/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Please login"
Require valid-user
```

**UPDATE:SOLVED**

I solved this issue by editing my .htaccess to this. For a full explination see my reply to Capsule below or my answer below.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev.mywebsite.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mywebsite.com/dev/$1 [L,NC,QSA]

SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/dev require_auth=true

# show Basic auth dialogue only when SHOW_AUTH is set
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /www/live_website/dev/.htpasswd
AuthName “Please login“

# Setup a deny/allow
Order Deny,Allow

# Deny from everyone
Deny from all

# except if either of these are satisfied
Satisfy any

# 1. a valid authenticated user
Require valid-user

# or 2. the "require_auth" var is NOT set
Allow from env=!require_auth
```

Comment: It should already work like you intent it to. You must have another `Require valid-user` impacting `/www/live_website/`. OR, you ask for ressources that are located in the `dev` website, from the live one.

Comment: Hello Capsule, thank you for the swift reply. You are right it appears some resources that were being used by my dev site came from the live site. I solved this issue by making the subdomain dev.mywebsite.com redirect to mywebsite.com/dev/ after that I have .htaccess ask for the password.  I will upload what my new .htaccess file looks like in my question. Thank you again!

Comment: A subdomain is not a subdirectory. A subdomain was dev.mywebsite.com, while a subdirectory is mywebsite.com/dev.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing the subdomain from dev.mywebsite.com to redirect to mywebsite.com/dev and then had .htaccess request login credentials upon the redirect.

The new .htaccess file in my dev folder below.

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev.mywebsite.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mywebsite.com/dev/$1 [L,NC,QSA]

    SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/dev require_auth=true

    # show Basic auth dialogue only when SHOW_AUTH is set
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /www/live_website/dev/.htpasswd
    AuthName “Please login“

    # Setup a deny/allow
    Order Deny,Allow

    # Deny from everyone
    Deny from all

    # except if either of these are satisfied
    Satisfy any

    # 1. a valid authenticated user
    Require valid-user

    # or 2. the "require_auth" var is NOT set
    Allow from env=!require_auth
```